# How to submit/post an image directly to TinEye via HTML form?

Tags: html, forms

So, I have a custom newtab page where I show some options for reverse image searching when I drag something over the page.

Here is my not working code for TinEye:

```
<form
  action="https://tineye.com/search"
  method="POST"
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
  target="_blank"
>
  TinEye
  <input type="file" name="url" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And here is my working code for google:

```
<form
  action="https://images.google.de/searchbyimage/upload"
  method="POST"
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
  target="_blank"
>
  Google Images
  <input type="file" name="encoded_image" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I looked in the code from TinEye (They have public sourcemaps, pretty cool!) and think the search/upload logic works completely through JavaScript and does not work with a form submit like mine, but if someone of you has a solution that works somehow, without me needing to upload the image first to a server, please tell me.

Thanks in advance

---

I found the solution by myself and it looks like this:

```
<form
  action="https://tineye.com/search/upload"
  method="POST"
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
  target="_blank"
>
  TinEye
  <input type="file" name="image" />
  <input type="submit" hidden />
</form>
```

I just tried a bit of random stuff, added the "upload" to the url like it needs to be for google and did take the parameter name ("image") from the input at the TinEye start page.

Comment: https://services.tineye.com/developers/tineyeapi/api_reference#search + you're using a `get` request instead of `post`

Comment: Yeah, my wrong, I did try a few other things after POST did not work and pasted the wrong code. sorry. Does not work with POST either. Your linking me stuff from the API but i don't want to use the API I just want the page to open with my Image already uploading, like the google example does.

Comment: The API is not free - Check their FAQ